# Send randomly-generated number to view

Tags: java, android

How can I generate a random number and then send it to the emulator?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    TextView number1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Random generator = new Random();
            int number1 = generator.nextInt(13);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number1);

        number1.setText(Float.toString(number1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app? Are you seeing anything on the screen? Any errors?

Comment: What is in your activity_main.xml?

Comment: Should read into the android dev guidelines from google. They are really good.

Comment: Don't use `public static void main(String[] args) {`, that's not how you run an app

Answer (score 0):

Move number generator to onCreate() method and remove main(). You should also change your int variable name.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random generator = new Random();
    int number = generator.nextInt(13);

    number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    number1.setText(Integer.toString(number));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your random number is being generated and set as the value for the int number1, which only exists in the context of the Main() method.

Generate your random number as part of the onCreate method. (n.b. untested code)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random generator = new Random();
    int myRandomInteger= generator.nextInt(13);

    number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    number1.setText(Integer.toString(myRandomInteger));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the `main` method - according to the lifecycle - the `onCreate` method will be called and during this time you can call your random number generator - and then set the returned value to your `TextView`.

See the suggested changes below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    TextView number1;
    //removed the main function from here -
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number1); 
      //call the method that gets a random number - and set this to the Text field   
        number1.setText(getRandomNumber());
    }

   //I have moved the code from your main function into this "helper" method
   private int getRandomNumber(){
      Random generator = new Random();
      int number1 = generator.nextInt(13);
      return number1;       
   }
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if this helps.